# SSIS alternatives for ETL in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, etl, data-warehouse

Please could you all assist us in answering what we believe to be a rather simple question, but is proving to be really difficult to get a solution to. We have explored things like Data Bricks and Snowflake for our Azure based data warehouse, but keep getting stuck at the same point.

Do you have any info you could share with us around how you would move data from an Azure database (source) to another Azure database (destination) without using SSIS ?

We would appreciate any info you would be able to share with us on this matter.

Looking forward to hearing from you
Thanks
Dom

Comment: Welcome aboard Dominic. Currently is possible to move data from a SQL to SQL database using the Azure Data Factory. There is another requirement that must be fullfilled?

Comment: Thanks Leandro - we will explore this in more detail